Getting thousands of 404 pages for my website with a common URL and a .htm extension
I am seeing many 404 pages ending with the .htm extension in Google Search Console:
Sometimes they aren't appearing, but other times there are more than 1,000 pages in a day.
What can I do about these?

Your site may have been hacked - check for unknown scripts and malware that could be generating these random URLs. In most cases 404's don't really impact anything other than your crawl budget - see Google's Blog: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site#:~:text=If%20you%20see%20404%20errors,you%20can%20safely%20ignore%20them.
